# codeigniter dependant dropdown, there was a issue while using xmlhttp

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am using dependent drop down in my project. I have checked my code several time but still there was an error.

Data has loaded to 'Category' drop down. when Iam select item from 'Category' following message will be displayed. Not data loaded into 'Sub category'.

***"There was a problem while using XMLHTTP"***

please look at my code

```
<!-- /.Category -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Product Category</label>
                                            <select name="category_id" class="form-control col-sm-5" id="category" onchange="get_category(this.value)">
                                                <option value="">Select Product Category</option>
                                                <?php if (!empty($category)): ?>
                                                    <?php foreach ($category as $v_category) : ?>
                                                        <option value="<?php echo $v_category->category_id; ?>"
                                                            <?php
                                                            if (!empty($product_info)) {
                                                                echo $v_category->category_id == $product_category->category_id ? 'selected' : '';
                                                            }
                                                            ?> >
                                                            <?php echo $v_category->category_name; ?>
                                                        </option>
                                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- /.Sub Category -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Subcategory<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                            <select name="subcategory_id" class="form-control col-sm-5" id="subcategory">
                                                <option value="">Product Subcategory</option>
                                                <?php if (!empty($subcategory)): ?>
                                                    <?php foreach ($subcategory as $v_subcategogy) : ?>
                                                        <option value="<?php echo $v_subcategogy->subcategory_id; ?>"
                                                            <?php
                                                            if (!empty($product_info)) {
                                                                echo $v_subcategogy->subcategory_id == $product_info->subcategory_id ? 'selected' : '';
                                                            }
                                                            ?> >
                                                            <?php echo $v_subcategogy->subcategory_name; ?>
                                                        </option>
                                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
```

AJAX CODE (i think issue in the response (*req.status == 200*) part.)

```
//*********************************************
//     Product Category to Subcategory
//*********************************************

function get_category(str) {

    if (str == '') {
        $("#subcategory").html("<option value=''>Select Subcategory</option>");
    } else {
        $("#subcategory").html("<option value=''>Select Subcategory</option>");

        var link = getBaseURL();
        var strURL = link + "admin/product/get_subcategory_by_category/" + str;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();
        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {
                        var result = req.responseText;
                        //alert(result);
                        $("#subcategory").html("<option value=''>Select Subcategory</option>");
                        $("#subcategory").append(result);
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
            req.open("POST", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you're not using `ajax` when you've `jQuery` loaded

Comment: Mr. Tushar. please explain

Comment: Read: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

It will help you if you are looking for Dependent dropdown (library) using CodeIgniter.

Look over It:  [Dependent dropdown (library)](http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/1087-updated-24112012-dependent-dropdown-library/http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/1087-updated-24112012-dependent-dropdown-library/)